# "Error while loading shared libraries" on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, software-center, dependencies, shared-library

I have faced with this error with two programs on a newly installed Ubuntu 18.04.

I get the following error message when I run "lifeograph" after instaling it using Software Center or Synaptic.

> lifeograph: error while loading shared libraries: libatkmm-1.6.so.1:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I get the same error "while loading shared libraries" with another program, "keepassxc":

> keepassxc: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Network.so.5:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried to run the following command but it did not help:

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
```

Ubuntu 18.04 is a LTS release. Above mentioned programs are from official repositories. Getting such errors on a a freshly installed LTS system is surprising.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: After the initial install, did you ever update the package database?  The package installer should have brought in all dependencies, or fail.

Comment: @ubfan1 Yes, I did. It seems they are installed without any dependency problem, but they don't run.

Answer (score 0):

Checking my system, I see multiple copies of that library buried under /snap/gnome-system-monitor/...  so of course the loader cannot find them.
Either add a link yourself to the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu location pointing to one of these installed /snap locations, or add one of the /snap... locations to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
  Maybe your package manager defaults to offering snap packages when available -- try changing that default.  You can explicitly use apt-get in a terminal:
 <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>   then

```
sudo apt-get install libatkmm-1.6-1v5
```