# Numerous libxxxx... libraries missing when trying to launch applications

Tags: package-management, 18.04, libraries, shared-library

I just freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 but some things went wrong in the process and now I seem to be missing some libraries.
I often can not launch programs after I installed them due to "error while loading shared libraries"
here are some examples:

```
golol@golol:~$ sudo gparted
[sudo] password for golol: 
Unit -.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
/usr/sbin/gpartedbin: error while loading shared libraries: libatkmm-
1.6.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
golol@golol:~$ sudo partitionmanager
partitionmanager: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Gui.so.5:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
golol@golol:~$ sudo inkscape
inkscape: error while loading shared libraries: libwpg-0.3.so.3: cannot
open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

There seems to be a general issue not related to gparted, partitionmanager or inkscape.
I tried to install specifically these missing libraries but I only found them as .rpm online and didn't know how to *correctly* install them.

I did see this question:
["Error while loading shared libraries" on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057014/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)
But I don't fully understand the given response and trying

```
sudo apt-get install libatkmm-1.6-1v5
```

just gave the response that the package is up to date.
Here you can see for the package missing for inkscape that I can locate it in various folders bit inkscape seems to not find it!

```
dpkg --listfiles libwpg-0.3-3
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwpg-0.3.so.3.0.1
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libwpg-0.3-3
/usr/share/doc/libwpg-0.3-3/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libwpg-0.3-3/copyright
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwpg-0.3.so.3
golol@golol:~$ sudo inkscape
inkscape: error while loading shared libraries: libwpg-0.3.so.3: cannot 
open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Thank you for your help.

Edit: What went wrong during installation:
The installation initially crashed/stopped while installing grub2. When I started the installation again, the partition manager showed me that some Ubuntu was installed. I thought this might be a broken install so I deleted the partitions and created new ones. Because of something I read online, besides a root, home and swap partition I now added some EFI filesystem partition. This time the installation hung up on grub2 and I cancelled it. Again I had an Ubuntu on my partitions now and just stuck with it. I use boot repair to reinstall grub from the bootstick and could now boot into my system.
Later I found out about the difference between BIOS and UEFI and that my Win8 is legacy, which might be related to the issue.

Comment: What specifically went wrong when you installed Ubuntu? If the installation process was interrupted before it was finished it'll be much easier to reinstall Ubuntu rather than fixing a broken install. Also assuming that the install is fairly new so you haven't spent too much time working on it yet.

Comment: Okay, I will add this to the question because it could be a bit lengthy for a comment.

Comment: Forgot to mention: I am honestly scared to reinstall Ubuntu because: 1. I don't know how to make sure the same thing doesn't happen again. 2. I would like to not run into the UEFI/Legacy mixing issue again and install it as only Bios, which I don't know how to do. 3. I don't have a windows cd on me so if removing Ubuntu breaks my windows boot process I can't repair it.

Comment: I can't think of an idea how to fix your problem without reinstalling Ubuntu. Maybe until you're comfortable how to multiboot on a machine you can just delete Ubuntu, claim the space for Windows 8 and for the meantime you can play with Ubuntu on a virtual machine. While you doing that, learn how to dualboot Ubuntu with your current configuration and prepare a Windows 8 boot image just in case you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved my problem (it seems) although I am not sure why this worked as a solution.
First I ran sudo apt upgrade (I had to take some steps beforehand to make it work, but I don't remeber them)
Then I reinstalled *all* my packages. This might not be the smartest thing to do but I noticed that sudo apt install --reinstall libxxxx did its job now.
I found a script online that went through all my packages and did just that. It took quite long but in the end the errors disappeared and I can now run the software I wanted to.